# Publish option missing in visual studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to deploy an application to aws from within visual studio (2017), but the publish and publish to aws beanstalk options do not appear when I right click the project in the solution explorer. I have installed the aws toolkit, and when working with other projects, the options are present. I'm still new to visual studio, so it's possible I'm missing a simple step, but any help would be appreciated, as I have spent several hours searching for an answer.